# AnyLogic Parameter Variation Experiment Error Handling

Tags: anylogic

I'm working on a model and running into an issue with my AnyLogic parameter variation experiment. Sometimes, an error pops up, and the whole thing stops before it completes all the runs and replications.

I tried using the "onError" function as suggested in the AnyLogic-help, where I placed it in the parameter variation window. My idea was to call getEngine().finish() to end the current replication and let the experiment continue with the next replication. Here is the onError function:
[image]

But the experiment still stops on an error. Any idea where I might have gone wrong, or is there another way to handle errors and move on to the next replication?

Any help or suggestions would be awesome.